# call overwritten child function within parent function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, syntax-error, virtual-inheritance

is it possible in c++ to call a child function from a parent function.

Let's take an example: The parent class defines in a function (parse) the general workflow. The workflow then calls different methods which represent part of the flow (parseElementA). These functions can be overwritten by the child class, if not the standart function, which is part of the parent shall be used.

My issue is: I create a child object and execute the workflow function (parse). When the overwritten function (parseElementA) is called within the workflow function it calls the function from the parent and not from the child.
What could i do so it calls the overwritten function in child.

```
    class Parent {
      public:
        void parse() { parseElementA(); }
        virtual void parseElementA() { printf("parent\n"); }
    };

    class Child : public Parent {
      public: 
        void parseElementA() { printf("child\n"); }
    };

    Child child;
    child.parse();
```

the output is parent. What can I do that it returns child.

Thank you very much for any advice.

Comment: First I edited your code, but I haven't got enough characters to add (semicolons) and added my answer so that it compiles fine...

Comment: @jHack but was there really a problem? I can't see any problem in the fixed code, so I'm not sure what the question is about now...

Comment: @juanchopanza: semicolons are missing after `printf`... I could add spaces because a colon was missing after `public`, then I tried to edit again but couldn't add only 2 characters.

Comment: @jHack, @Steve, OK I see. But OP claims certain behaviour, which was impossible given the syntax errors. I was just curious as to what OP's real, compiling, code looked like.

Comment: @Steve: Homonyms: I think you mean "overridden" & not "overwritten"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After fixing compiler errors from your code, [it works fine](http://www.ideone.com/4t6kU).

Comment: @ianmmilind added my corrections too (I was editing OP questions), but upvoted you though

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cstdio>

class Parent {
        public:
                void parse() { parseElementA(); }
                virtual void parseElementA() { printf("parent\n"); }
};

class Child : public Parent {
        public:
                void parseElementA() { printf("child\n"); }
};

int main() {

   Child child;
   child.parse();

   return 0;
}
```